# Default value for template parameter, followed by non-type parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization, default-parameters, non-type

I'm struggling to make this code work

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U = int, auto... Params>
class Foo {};

int main()
{
    auto foo1 = Foo<int, int, 1, 2, 3>{};
    auto foo2 = Foo<int, 1, 2, 3>{}; // I want it to compile
}
```

It looks like I need some hack. I tried partial specialization, but it doesn't work either

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U, auto... Params>
class Foo {};

template <typename T, auto... Params>
class Foo<T, int, Params...> {};

int main()
{
    auto foo1 = Foo<int, int, 1, 2, 3>{};
    auto foo2 = Foo<int, 1, 2, 3>{}; // I want it to compile
}
```

I can't find anything closely related to this, help pls :)

Comment: This looks weird, what are you actually trying to do here?  Please show a representative implementation of `Foo`.

Comment: The closest I could get so far is `Foo<list<int, int>, 1, 2, 3>`.

Comment: @PaulSanders, actually, I'm trying to write constrained_type - a class, which applies set of predicates to the contained value. The value itself contains in an optional. I want to parametrize over different kids of optionals (for example std::optional and compact_optional)

Source code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/JoshuaJakowlew/constrained_type/blob/master/main.cpp):

Comment: I think this can't be done. The problem can be deduced to this: `struct A {} A;`. This means that `A` can be a type when a type is expected by the parser, but it can also be a value when a value is expected by the parser. So it's the calling code that must resolve whether something is a type or a value. In your case, this is undecided.

Comment: @lorro, if this is true - it's so stupid, that compiler cannot differentiate between type and non-type parameters

Comment: @JoshuaJakowlew Quite the contrary - I gave you an example where it's theoretically undecidable (how would you interpret `Foo<int, A, 2>` after the declaration above?). Since `struct` definitions were earlier - actually, with `typedef`, back in the C-times -, they must remain when we implement new things. So type vs. value decision would create ambiguity. BUT: this is not really a problem. You can always wrap a type to a value (e.g. `id<int>()`), or you can pack the numbers in a type (e.g. `std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately due to the way that template deduction works, this is ...not going to work.

Here's one alternative approach where the first template parameter is always a tuple, with one or two types, with the second type defaulting to an `int`:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, auto ...Params> class Foo;

template<typename T, typename U, auto ...Params>
class Foo< std::tuple<T, U>, Params...> {

    // Your template goes here, making use of T and U
};

template<typename T, auto ...Params>
class Foo< std::tuple<T>, Params...> : Foo<std::tuple<T, int>, Params...> {

    // Might need to define some cleanups here, like a delegating constructor,
    // and/or delegated overload operators.

};

Foo<std::tuple<char>, 3, 4> defaulted;

Foo<std::tuple<char, float>, 3, 4> non_defaulted;
```

With a little bit more elbow grease it should be possible to require a formal `std::tuple` only when the 2nd optional type needs to be specified, and just specify the primary type directly (although that will create some avoidable confusion if the primary type is a `std::tuple`, itself).